# Missing native library to build an Haskell package with Cabal, on Linux

Tags: linux, haskell, cabal

i get an error when trying to build an Haskell package which depends on a native C library, even though the header file seems to be at its place. The error says:

```
Missing (or bad) header file
```

What is the meaning of this error? How can i find out more? The file is not missing since i can find it in my system, under `/usr/include/`. I tried to use the `--extra-include-dirs` option in order to point Cabal to the header file which is present in my system, but i still get the error. So the file is not *missing*, how can it be *bad*?

This is really a generic question about how to troubleshoot this kind of issues, but here are the details about my system:

- Package to install: `zlib`
- Missing header: `zlib.h`
- Header position in my system: `/usr/include/zlib.h`
- Operative system: Ubuntu 16.04

I installed any possible Ubuntu `zlib-dev` package i could find, including 32 bit versions

Comment: Is this the only error? Can you run a  verbose build?

Comment: Could you provide the entire output including your command?  Also, consider trying to install just `zlib` (ex: `cabal install zlib`) instead of building whatever larger project you're working in order to shrink the output a bit.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I was able to install  `zlib`. I have the `zlib1g-dev` system package installed.

Comment: thanks @n.m. for the hint. I ran the command again with verbosity `-v3` and i have got `/usr/include/zlib.h:34:19: fatal error: zconf.h: No such file or directory` which is way more helpful for troubleshooting. You could write an answer suggesting to increase verbosity, that is what i was looking for, albeit simple. That was actually also suggested by cabal itself after the error! Anyway hopefully an answer can help somebody else

Comment: Also the suggestion from @ThomasM.DuBuisson is helpful, i was already following that

Comment: I had tried `-vvv` before, which is common for many other commands, but got a parsing error, so i thought that `-v` was the maximum i could ask for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you increase build verbosity with say `-v3`, you will get actual compiler error messages.  In this case

```
/usr/include/zlib.h:34:19: fatal error: zconf.h: No such file or directory
```

A quick googling of the name `zlib.h` reveals that this is a confirmed open [Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zlib/+bug/1155307).